# Access the Library List Data Through The Rest Public api

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

We are having PDF files on the Library Object. We are using HTML Native app for accessing the REST APIs from the Salesforce. We need to get the list of Library IDs from the Salesforce. For that we developed the below REST API.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/LibraryList/*')

global class LibraryListController 

{

@HttpGet

//global static List<ContentWorkspaceDoc> retrieve()

global static List<ContentWorkspace> retrieve()

{

   RestRequest req = RestContext.request;

    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

    res.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

     res.addHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

    res.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');

    String Id = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1); 

    //List <ContentWorkspace> Lib= [SELECT ParentId,ContentDocumentId,ContentWorkspaceId,Id FROM ContentWorkspaceDoc]; 
    List <ContentWorkspace> Lib= [SELECT Id,Name FROM ContentWorkspace];               
    return Lib;
 }
}
```

We are sending our APIs through our site. Example url  `https://ap2.salesforce.com/SampleSite/services/apexrest/LibraryList`.
If we are trying to access this from `Workbench`, we get the data. But if we run this URL publicly we are not getting response.The remaining all APIs we are able to get data.

Can any one please suggest how to get data from the Library?

Please help us with your suggestions

Comment: 1) Are you sure that you put correct url (site url?)
@

Comment: 2) Are you sure that you have added page to site(site user has access)?
3) As a response, you should do like resp.responseBody = Blob.ValueOf(JSON.serialize(Lib));

Comment: HI Kurunve Ti am putting the correct URL. Because we are using same path for another 15 Rest classes. All are working fine. But only for this API i am not able to get data. I added page to correct site.  As per your suggestion i added resp.responseBody = Blob.ValueOf(JSON.serialize(Lib));  . But still not able to get data. Can you give me  any other suggestion

Comment: I checked in workbench and developer console. It is working fine.But when i am running trough the browser i am getting Empty responce

Comment: what response are you exactly getting - with status and headers?

Comment: If i run through Workbench i am getting the Libraries list along with id and Name of the Library. But if run through Browser its giving <responce> with blank page.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 16:47:02 GMT
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src https:; script-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src https: data:; font-src https: data:; report-uri /_/ContentDomainCSPNoAuth?type=mydomain
Set-Cookie: BrowserId=O_xTanZaRGi5p9i4WVFI_A;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Fri, 06-May-2016 16:47:02 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Comment: Content-Encoding: gzip Transfer-Encoding: chunked [ { "attributes" : { "type" : "ContentWorkspace", "url" : "/services/data/v35.0/sobjects/ContentWorkspace/058L00000005nMLIAY" }, "Id" : "058L00000005nMLIAY", "Name" : "MyVarian" }, { "attributes" : { "type" : "ContentWorkspace", "url" : "/services/data/v35.0/sobjects/ContentWorkspace/058L00000005nMBIAY" }, "Id" : "058L00000005nMBIAY", "Name" : "Sales&Marketing" } ]

Comment: Is any other way to pass rest api for getting the pdf's of the library